# Is there a way to submit a text post on reddit via a url

Tags: reddit

I know there's a way to submit a link post to reddit.

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=myTitle&url=http://www.exampledsfsd.com
```

which pops up a page like this with the title and url filled in

[image]

Is there a way to initiate the submission of a text post?
It really just needs to get to the "text" tab and fill on the "text" field in this page

[image]

Just to be clear, I'm aware of the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api). I don't want to take an approach that requires setting up a reddit account, a reddit app, and manage authentication for the user. I actually already tried this approach but there are issues with using it with other aspects of my site. I'm looking for something simple like the submit Link Post above

Comment: I don't have a reddit account, but : What can you see when you "inspect" the submission button? You should be able to see some javascript performing an ajax request. Usually, you'll need to make a POST with the same parameters, including the login token

Comment: On the other hand, there is a Reddit API that you could find useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301342/reddit-submit-api-500-error?rq=1

Comment: I believe that either reproducing what the submission button does on that page or using the Reddit API will require me to authenticate and authorize the user first. And I don't want to go down this route (i've already tried and there are other nuances that don't make sense for my site)

Comment: You will need to authenticate the user anyhow, I cannot even see the form without logging in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823114/post-to-reddit-via-url?rq=1

Comment: The reddit link submission I posted does not require authentication. I'm looking for a similar solution that does not require authentication

Comment: I saw the SO but that's asking about posting links which I already know how to do. I'm looking for a way to post text

Comment: In that case is strongly probable that that post request doesn't need it neither. Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't help here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply guessed at this one, but it worked for me. Use `text` as the parameter instead of `url`.

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=myTitle&text=testing
```

Of course, you'll need to url encode your text.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't try that myself. If anyone finds authoritative doc about this, I'd love to see it still. Thanks!

Comment: Not working now

Answer (score 18):

As CoderDennis said, you can use the submit page with the `text` parameter (urlencoded).  You should also set `selftext` to true, which sets the displayed tab to the self post tab (although it's not required as that is inferred based off of the `text` parameter).

Some of the things in the [doc for `/api/submit`](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_submit) still apply to that page (although only a few).  You can see exactly how it works by looking at the code used for the actual page on reddit's GitHub ([here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/b1fe5d949ca43ca272f1382523d4b9b783eea15b/r2/r2/controllers/front.py#L1222-L1283) and [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/3693e17d15ed1bb514d315ffeadeeb582598898e/r2/r2/lib/pages/pages.py#L3259-L3301))

For submitting a text post, what you'll want is a URL like this:

[`https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use&selftext=true&text=Urlencoded%20self%20post%20text`](https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use&selftext=true&text=Urlencoded%20self%20post%20text)

This will open the submit page for `/r/test` to submit a new post with the title "`Title to use`", and a post body of "`Urlencoded self post text`".

Here are all of the parameters, for reference:

- `title`: Title of the post to submit
- `url`: URL to submit to
- `text`: Text of the self post
- `selftext`: Whether to default to the self text tab (`true` to do so).  If `text` is present, then it will default to displaying that tab anyways.
- `resubmit`: Whether to resubmit the post (if not present and submitting a link post, and another post already links there, you will be taken to that post instead with an option to resubmit it).

Comment: This answer should have gotten the bounty!

Comment: What *exactly* does `selftext=true` do? I don't see any difference in the resulting page without it.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It tells it to use the text tab.  It's implied by the `text` parameter, but e.g. `https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use` ( https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use ) will default to a link, but `https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use&selftext=true` ( https://www.reddit.com/r/test/submit?title=Title%20to%20use&selftext=true ) will default to text. (So, you need it if you want a link to submit a text post without putting text into the text field by default)